# Don't receive shadow on plane in unity urp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity v2021.3.10f1 with URP. In my project i have a plane which i don't want to receive shadows on it. with URP the "receive shadow" checkbox is not shown in the inspector. anyone Know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Material Settings]

In your material's settings, there's an option to receive/not receive shadows.